# In Go, how do stay in a for loop, but print a different output if user guesses too high or too low

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, random

I'm trying to develop a guessing game in **GO** that gives the user three attempts to guess the random number correctly.

It mostly seems to work, I'm using a for loop to count the amount of lives left. If I guess the number correctly, it prints what I want:

> "You guessed it!"

But the issue is, say for example, the random number is **5**. If I guessed **4**, it would print

> "Too low"

which is correct, but in the second attempt if I was to guess **6**, it would still say

> "Too low"

Alternatively, if the random number was **5**, and on the first attempt I guessed **6**, it would print

> "Too high"

If I was to guess **4** on the second attempt, it would still say

> "Too high"

I think I'm getting caught in the for loop somewhere, but I don't know how to exit it without resetting the attempts count back to 3.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    secret := getRandomNumber()
    fmt.Println(secret)

    fmt.Println("Guess the number")

    _guess := guessRandomNumber()

    for i := 3; i > 0; i-- {

        if _guess < secret {
            fmt.Println("Too low")
            fmt.Println("You have", i, "guesses left.")
        } else if _guess < secret {
            fmt.Println("Too low")
            fmt.Println("You have", i, "guesses left.")

            guessRandomNumber()
        } else if _guess > secret {
            fmt.Println("Too high")
            fmt.Println("You have", i, "guesses left.")

            guessRandomNumber()
        }

        if _guess == secret {
            fmt.Println("You guessed it!")
            i = 0
        } else if _guess < secret {
            fmt.Println("Too low")
            fmt.Println("You have", i, "guesses left.")

            guessRandomNumber()
        } else if _guess > secret {
            fmt.Println("Too high")
            fmt.Println("You have", i, "guesses left.")

            guessRandomNumber()
        }
    }

}

func getRandomNumber() int {

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Int() % 11
}

func guessRandomNumber() int {
    var guess int
    //fmt.Println("Guess again:")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &guess)
    return guess
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm really liking **GO** so far.

Comment: Your subsequent `guessRandomNumber()` call statements do not assign their result to anything, leaving the `_guess` variable declared above the loop unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning the output of your function `guessRandomNumber()` to your `_guess`. Apart from this also you're using extra `if-else`, which are not required. Also you're giving 4 attempts to user instead of 3. You can try:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    secret := getRandomNumber()
    fmt.Println(secret)

    fmt.Println("Guess the number")

    var _guess int
    for i := 3; i > 0; i-- {
        _guess = guessRandomNumber()
        if _guess == secret {
            fmt.Println("You guessed it!")
            break
        } else if _guess < secret {
            fmt.Println("Too low")
            fmt.Println("You have", i-1, "guesses left.")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Too high")
            fmt.Println("You have", i-1, "guesses left.")
        }
        if i != 1 {
            fmt.Println("Guess Again:")
        }
        
    }
}

func getRandomNumber() int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Int() % 11
}

func guessRandomNumber() int {
    var guess int
    //fmt.Println("Guess Number:")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &guess)
    return guess
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/aOI-CG4S-

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I ended up using a for loop with a switch statement for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a for loop with a switch statement to solve the issue.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
secret := getRandomNumber()
fmt.Println(secret)

fmt.Println("Guess the number")

_guess := guessRandomNumber()

guessCorrect := false
guessCount := 3

for guessCorrect == false && guessCount != 0 {

    switch {
    case _guess < secret:
        fmt.Println("Too low,", guessCount, "guesses left.")
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &_guess)
        guessCount--
        continue
    case _guess > secret:
        fmt.Println("Too high", guessCount, "guesses left.")
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &_guess)
        guessCount--
        continue
    default:
        fmt.Println("You got it!")
        guessCorrect = true
    }

}
}

func getRandomNumber() int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Int() % 11
}

func guessRandomNumber() int {
    var guess int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &guess)
    return guess
}
```